# Is there a reason that shorthand options can't be stacked for Git's stash command?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

There is a pattern in the Unix CLI world where frequently-used options are given a single-letter shorthand, and these can usually be combined together, or *stacked*. A very common example of this can be found with the `rm` command, which can remove directories recursively. These three commands are equivalent:

```sh
rm --recursive --force .
rm -r -f .
rm -rf .
```

Git has many sub-commands, each with many options. I've become used to Git allowing its shorthand options to be stacked for ease of use, like many other well-written CLI tools. For example:

```sh
git commit -am 'Create new commit message'
```

I've found that `git stash` is at least one exception, where the shorthands for the useful options `--keep-index` and `--include-untracked` cannot be stacked into `-ku`:

```sh
git stash -k -u  # This works
git stash -ku    # This doesn't
```

Is there a specific reason for this, other than that it hasn't been implemented? Are there other examples where Git options can't be stacked, and do these examples have specific reasons?

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  The `git stash` command was a big shell script that didn't parse options very well, but has been converted to C code that uses a better option parser, and probably should now accept `-ku`.

Comment: You're right. `git stash -ku` doesn't work in Git 2.25, but it does in version 2.27

Comment: @torek that's a solid answer if you can write it as one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all but very recent versions of Git, `git stash` has been a shell script that (for whatever reason) didn't use Git's option parser.  Starting in Git 2.22, there was a project to rewrite it in C.  The C rewrite has a proper option parser.  The rewrite, however, wasn't quite *done* until recently, and the old shell script version was still around.

[As you reported in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258717/is-there-a-reason-that-shorthand-options-cant-be-stacked-for-gits-stash-comman?noredirect=1#comment111862510_63258717), `git stash -ku` does work in Git 2.27, but not in Git 2.25.  Git 2.27 is the first version in which the old shell script version is truly gone; probably this is when the option parsing was finally switched over as well.